# Get bytes from array function in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, byte

I need to get the bytes from an array of bytes starting at a certain index and for a certain length (4). How can I get this?

Note: I don't want to use the Array.copy sub as it is not a function. I need to put it in something like `Sub MySub(`[argument as byte()]`the_function_I_Need(Array, index, length))`.

Comment: Is this an array of bytes? If not, can you be more specific about the array type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Function the_function_you_need(ByVal arr As Byte(), ByVal ix As Integer, _
    ByVal len As Integer) As Byte()

    Dim arr2 As Byte() = New Byte(len - 1)
    Array.Copy(arr, ix, arr2, 0, len)
    Return arr2

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
Dim portion As Byte() = New Byte(length - 1) {}
Array.Copy(originalArray, index, portion, 0, length)
```

The "- 1" is because of VB taking the last element index rather than the size.

EDIT: I missed the bit about not wanting to use `Array.Copy`. (Was it there when I posted the answer, or did you edit it in within the five minutes "grace period"?)

Just wrap this into a method if you really need to. While there are alternatives using LINQ etc, this will be the most efficient way of doing it if you genuinely want a new array.

There's also [`ArraySegment(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) if you're happy to use a wrapper around the existing array - but that's not the same thing.

Comment: "I don't want to use the Array.copy", I know about that but I need something where the bytes are returned so I don't have to have the `Dim portion`

Comment: @Jonathan: you wrap array.copy in a function.

Comment: I know I have done that in the mean time just wanted to know if there was an "out the box" way?

Comment: arr.Skip(index).Take(length).ToArray() perhaps?

Comment: @Jonathan: Doh - missed that bit of the question, sorry. Just write it as a method if you really have to. Will edit.